# Connect to Splunk from DBeaver

Tags: jdbc, splunk, dbeaver

My question is a simple how to.
I'm aware of [this link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/splunk-jdbc-dbvr.rst), but can't get the driver for it is not free to download!
Maybe, somewhere out there, there is another jdbc driver for Splunk?